# Volley JsonObjectRequest send headers in GET Request

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to send some authentication headers from `GET` request and I tried using `Volley JsonObjectRequest` call :

```
Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("token","fghjbvjhnjjk");
        activity.showDialog();
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
                new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(tag, response.toString());
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(response, code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(tag, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.e(tag, "Site Info Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(null,code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        req.setShouldCache(true);
```

But its showing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.hashCode()' on a null object reference
        at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:136)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.<init>(JsonRequest.java:58)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.<init>(JsonObjectRequest.java:47)
```

I read somewhere that you can pass headers by making a `hashmap` and thus create a new `JsonObject` with that parameter. Maybe that will work on a `POST` request. Please help..

Comment: which is this "Request.java:136" line from above code ?

Comment: Thats the Request class from volley library.

Comment: just try `protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();` may be help you

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Well, the thing is simple and very precise. Passing headers to either GET or POST request, you need to override getHeaders method in JsonObjectRequest Class. This is how it will be done:

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,
                null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(tag, response.toString());
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(response, code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(tag, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Log.e(tag, "Site Info Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.hideDialog();
                try {
                    activity.onRequestServed(null,code);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }) {

            /**
             * Passing some request headers
             */
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                headers.put("key", "Value");
                return headers;
            }
        };
```