# how to update delivery status in PHP with this android code

Tags: android

I don't even know I am right are wrong. My situation of thinking is currently null. can some please tell me how to update `deliverystatus`

**This is code in AdapterClass**

```
delivered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String serverURL= PathUrls.pathUrl+"evs_updatedeliverystatus.php?db="+companyName.getString("companyName","")+"&invoiceid="+dlb.getInvoiceNo()+"&deliverystatus=1";
            JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(serverURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("update delivery list",response.toString());
                    deliveryListBeans.clear();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error DeliveryList:%n %s ", error);
                    Toast.makeText(ct,"NetworkError Not Responding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //Toast.makeText(ct, "companyName"+companyName.getString("companyName","").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
```

I already tested `PHP` with its `URL` it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check data follow

1 . Make sure serverURL is correct.

2 . While connecting to server you already call UpdateDeliveryList Activity. It will destroy current Activity

3 . When server return response successful: 
 deliveryListBeans.clear();// Clear list
 notifyDataSetChanged(); // and update list

I dont see you get deliverystatus from onResponse()

Comment: can you please check one more I just made some changes in code.  I removed Intent and directly calling `ServerURL`. I already checked `PHP` it is working fine.

Comment: In your         onResponse(JSONObject response)   .
        
 Log.d("update delivery list",response.toString()); // response is JSON return from your server.

You need parse response and show your data.

If your server exist form :   access_token in header. Please read this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35218464/volley-jsonobjectrequest-send-headers-in-get-request

Comment: Bap now I am having a different error. please check this link find have a solution to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031293/list-view-is-not-refreshing-even-after-calling-notifydatasetchanged?noredirect=1#comment79023468_46031293]