# list view is not refreshing even after calling notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android

> I am trying to refresh `listView` from Adapter class itself but it isn't refreshing don't know where the mistake is.

```
public class DeliveryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
DeliveryListAdapter ald;
Context ct;
private List<DeliveryListBean> deliveryListBeans;
SharedPreferences companyName;

public DeliveryListAdapter(Context ct,List<DeliveryListBean> deliveryListBeans)
{
    this.ct=ct;
    this.deliveryListBeans=deliveryListBeans;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return deliveryListBeans.size();
}

private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb)
{
    deliveryListBeans=dlb;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
//I skipped code for inflating because it is working fine.
delivered.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String serverURL= PathUrls.pathUrl+"evs_updatedeliverystatus.php?db="+companyName.getString("companyName","")+"&invoiceid="+dlb.getInvoiceNo()+"&deliverystatus=2";
            JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(serverURL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response.length()>0)
                    {
                        ald=new DeliveryListAdapter(ct,deliveryListBeans);
                        VolleyLog.v("update delivery list: %n %s ", response.toString());
                        try{
                            int status = response.getInt("status");
                            if (status==1)
                            {
                                Log.d("updated delivery",response.toString());
                                ald.updateResults(deliveryListBeans);
                                Toast.makeText(ct, "Delivery Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else if (status==0)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(ct, "Delivery Has been failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error DeliveryList:%n %s ", error);
                    Toast.makeText(ct,"NetworkError Not Responding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //Toast.makeText(ct, "companyName"+companyName.getString("companyName","").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            VolleySingleton.getsInstance().getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
```

I am using setOnclickListner for delivered button to update the status.
Status is updating but the list is not refreshing when I click on the delivery button.

Comment: i am assuming that you are doing update in ald.updateResults() method. Can u post that code?

Comment: `private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb)
{
    deliveryListBeans=dlb;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}` it in same adapter class

Comment: Are u sure u r getting the successful response?

Comment: yes I am getting successful response.

Comment: You messed with object reference somewhere. Double check the  reference adapter having previously and updated one is the same

Comment: @ADM I have just taken deliverylistadapter reference only for this refresh purpose. I haven't used it any where.

Comment: another way of doing is instead of passing new data to updateResults method you can try making an instance of adapter and passing in new data to the adapter constructor like:
adapter = new adapterUpdate(this, dlb);
then just call notifyDataSetChanged, like
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Pulkit sorry how can I do that. Need more specific. I am just learning this code right now. so understanding is problem to me

Comment: I assume you are calling updateResults() from somewhere paste the code in the question above

Comment: @SaiSi I'm missing one thing here what do u mean by list is not refreshing.. u haven't prepared new data in the response? U r passing the same list to updateResults()  method?

Comment: @Sai Si My guess is that you are creating a new adapter but your layout is still working with an existing adapter with old data. May be it's better not to create a new adapter but just call `updateResults(deliveryListBeans);`?

Comment: @Pulkit updateResult() is in the same AdapterClass `private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb)
{
    deliveryListBeans=dlb;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}`

Comment: @SaiSi deliveryListBeans still contains the old data in onResponse u r passing the same to _updateResults_ I think that's why it still shows the old list?

Comment: Try below after ald.updateResults(deliveryListBeans);
ald.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: could be possible what @Raghavendra said. Just make sure you are getting a different response form network and print deliverlistbean to log before notifyingdataset.

Comment: @Raghavendra so how can I solve this problem. can you suggest some code to do this?

Comment: @Pulkit I added `ald.notifyDataSetChanged` but still not refreshing the listview.

Comment: @SaiSi how u 've prepare List<DeliveryListBean> while calling first time? Use the same code in onResponse and preapare data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you create new Adapter??

```
 DeliveryListAdapter   ald=new DeliveryListAdapter(ct,deliveryListBeans);
```

I think you should just update for `deliveryListBeans`

and use this method of ADM user.

```
 private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb) {
deliveryListBeans.clear();
deliveryListBeans.addAll(dlb);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

I dont' see you use 'response' . You just check status from this var <- It is data from your server

Answer (score 1):

As i have said in comment you messed with reference.See the code below:

```
private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb) {
    deliveryListBeans=dlb;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Here you are assigning new list to the previous list so reference is changed . The adapter will never get notified cause adapter having previous reference . So the Solution is in two cases:
 if you want the old data too do as and second if you need only new data:

```
 private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb) {
    deliveryListBeans.addAll(dlb);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


 private void updateResults(List<DeliveryListBean> dlb) {
    deliveryListBeans.clear();
    deliveryListBeans.addAll(dlb);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Cool. Never thought of that

Comment: @ADM Still having the same problem I don't know why. This error is making my crazy

Comment: Thats because your deliveryListBeans never got updated . Debug the Code at respose

Answer (score 0):

> I found an alternative way of doing it. I just removed the `position` from `list` and the mistake is creating new object 
>   `ald=new DeliveryListAdapter(ct,deliveryListBeans);` 
>   you don't have to create any new object. What I did is

```
if (status==1)
{
Log.d("updated delivery",response.toString());
deliveryListBeans.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
Toast.makeText(ct, "Delivery Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```